# kcfinder filemanger not load directory

Tags: php, jquery, kcfinder

I attach 2 pic of my error of kceditor filemanger.
kcfinder filemanger not load directory of file

offical site : http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/

demo of offical site is good work, but When I download the code, run it doesn't work.

in config file i put 'disabled' => false.

what I do to solve this problem. 
[image]

**note** that other config is trust example:

```
   config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
   config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions on the upload directory?

Comment: this property is for linux not windows,

Comment: if anybody wants to know the KcFinder setting with CkEditor, Please check once https://github.com/neerajsinghsonu/KcFinder_CkEditor_Absolute_Url